# Trending Tags based on post views

Tags: plugins, php, posts, wp-query, tags

I'm looking to display a list of the most trending tags on my wordpress blog - based on views that the posts within these tags have had, with a max tag count of around 10.

I've looked into the tag_cloud that Wordpress provides but I'm getting lost in PHP as I'm a bit of a novice with this language. Does this even have this functionality available?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: paste the function you are using to measure postviews please

Comment: I actually don't have one yet - what function/plugin would you suggest?